Parameter cannot be processed because of the parameter name
I am running GitHub Actions under Windows. The desired action is very simple: upload a file to an artifactory based server.
Here is the job:
...
      - name: Upload
        with:
          XXX_USER: ${{ secrets.XXX_USER }}
          XXX_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.XXX_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          $count = git log --oneline | wc -l
          curl -u${{ secrets.XXX_USER }}:${{ secrets.XXX_TOKEN }} -T xxx "url"
...

If I run it like this, I have the following issue:
Invoke-WebRequest : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'u' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: 
-UseBasicParsing -Uri -UseDefaultCredentials -UserAgent.
At C:\Users\ci\.cache\act\fdd812efecf57ae1\act\workflow\2.ps1:3 char:6
+ curl -u: -T xxx "url ...

And if I add:
shell: cmd

I do not manage to access to the count value.
Can someone help solving that?

Use windows cmd syntax set count=$(git log --oneline | wc -l)

It does not work because "wc" is not recognized anymore then...
wc: unknown option -- )


try for /f %i in ('git log --oneline ^| find /c /v ""') do set count=%i

It makes "The syntax of the command is incorrect." I have tried it locally, it works but seems that the syntax is not allowed like this.
It was requiring a double %% before the i, it is now fine ! Thans to everyone
